# Rails/Cocoon : link_to_add_association to parent's parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, cocoon-gem

Cocoon gem for Rails allows dynamic adding/removing of nested forms fields.

We can use `data-association-insertion-node` to specify a jQuery selector where fields needs to be added.

My problem is that I'm using Cocoon with 2 levels nested fields in HTML tables and, for the second level, the target node must be link's parent's parent (not able to specify an id since parents are dynamic nested fields too...it has to be relative).

Cocoon's doc explains that `data-association-insertion-node` accepts any jQuery selector, `this` (link itself), or link's parent by default. But I don't see any method to specify link's parent's parent...or maybe I can reach parent through a jQuery selector but I've never seen that...

Comment: Just found `:parent` selector...but it just finds elements that are parent of others (ie. that have children). I don't think I can find a relative node just with selectors...